# SQL Server - Stored Proc Unexpected Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[SP_GetListOfGoodsReceiptNote] (@MinDate AS DATETIME, @MaxDate AS DATETIME, @CompanyID AS INT, @ProductID AS INT = NULL, @TradePartnerID AS INT = NULL, @PurchaseOrderID AS INT = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        CVH.ID, CVH.VoucherTypeID, CVH.VoucherDate, CVH.VoucherNumber, CVH.CompanyID, CVH.ReferenceVoucherID, CVH.VoucherAmount, CVH.VoucherStatus, CCP.TradePartnerID, CPMR.PartnerName
    FROM
        CruxVoucherHeader CVH
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CruxCorePurchase CCP ON CCP.VoucherHeaderID = CVH.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CruxPartnerMaster CPMR ON CCP.TradePartnerID = CPMR.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CruxVoucherBody CVB ON CVB.VoucherHeaderID = CVH.ID
    WHERE 
        CVH.VoucherDate >= @MinDate 
        AND CVH.VoucherDate <= @MaxDate
        AND CVH.CompanyID = @CompanyID
        AND CVH.VoucherTypeID = 3
        AND @ProductID IS NULL OR CVB.ProductID = @ProductID        
        AND @TradePartnerID IS NULL OR CCP.TradePartnerID = @TradePartnerID
        AND @PurchaseOrderID IS NULL OR CVH.ReferenceVoucherID = @PurchaseOrderID
END
```

I am having some problem in getting expected results from the above Stored Procedure. If you see, i have filtered the data with CVH.VoucherTypeID = 3 but still due some unknown reason i am getting the attached results. Am I making any conceptual mistake while writing the stored procedure. ?

This is how I am executing the Stored Procedure.

```
EXEC SP_GetListOfGoodsReceiptNote '2020/01/01','2021/02/02', 2, NULL, 74, NULL
```

[image: Result of Executed Stored Procedure]

Comment: Don't prefix sprocs with `sp_` it's reserved by Microsoft, and can cause performance issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `And` operator has precedence over `Or` operator,
So, if there is an expression  `A = B and C is null or C = D`
the `and` operator will be evaluated before  `or` operator part

so if you need to make `or` part evaluated first need put in parentheses
to be `A = B and (C is null or C = D)`

so the `WHERE` clause looks like it need parentheses as following:

```
WHERE CVH.VoucherDate >= @MinDate AND
      CVH.VoucherDate <= @MaxDate AND
      CVH.CompanyID = @CompanyID AND
      CVH.VoucherTypeID = 3 AND
      (@ProductID IS NULL OR CVB.ProductID = @ProductID) AND        
      (@TradePartnerID IS NULL OR CCP.TradePartnerID = @TradePartnerID) AND
      (@PurchaseOrderID IS NULL OR CVH.ReferenceVoucherID = @PurchaseOrderID)
```

for more information about Operator Precedence follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: On a side note, one should consider adding the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint to queries with the `(@SomeParameter IS NULL OR SomeColumn = (@SomeParameter)` pattern. SQL Server can then use constant folding to eliminate unneeded operators and optimize the query based on current parameter values.